# Insertion sort implemented on a csv file's lines in python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I'm looking to change my current insertion sort algorithm to sort files and I have no idea where to start. This is my code so far:

```
def insertionSort(arr):
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):

        key = arr[i]

        j = i-1

        while j >=0 and key < arr[j]:
            arr[j+1]=arr[j]
            j -=1
        arr[j+1] = key
```

Answer (score 0):

On What Basis of you want to sort the file? [e.g. On modified data or Name]

Just you need to use `import os`

**files coming from os.listdir() sorted alphabetically, thus not numerically**.

to sort by different mean

```
import os

def extractDataOrIndex(fileName):
    # do something to return date or index
    return date

def insertionSort(arr):

    for i in range(1,len(arr)):

        dataOrIndexOfCurrentFile = extractDataOrIndex(arr[i])   #have some logic here to extract date or Index 

        j = i-1

        dataOrIndexOfPrevFile = extractDataOrIndex(arr[j])     #have some logic here to extract date or Index

        while j >=0 and dataOrIndexOfCurrentFile < dataOrIndexOfPrevFile:
            arr[j+1]=arr[j]
            j -= 1
            if j>=0 :
                dataOrIndexOfPrevFile = extractDataOrIndex(arr[j])
        arr[j+1] = arr[i]

arddDir = os.listdir()

print(arddDir)  # you can see its already sorted by name

insertionSort(arddDir)

for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])    # to see sorted file on the basis of some parameter other than
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Duega,

I'm looking to sort based on a column alphabetically, where the column to be sorted by can be picked.